# "To break eggs" or "to crack eggs"?

Tags: verbs

> **?** She cracked an egg into the frying pan.

In this sentence, should *cracked* be replaced with *broke*?
I take that *to crack* means *to break, but without causing a complete separation of the parts*.

> The windshield of this car was cracked.

Comment: *Crack* is correct here.

Comment: Incidentally, the question should read “…without causing a complete separation…”, not “…without to cause a complete separation…”  ‘Without’ takes a gerund/participle(?), not an infinitive.

Comment: In the situation you mentioned, I'd use "crack" or "break" interchangeably, but if you accidentally dropped an egg on the floor, I'd say that you broke it, not that you cracked it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both verbs are quite commonly used with eggs.  Comparing various phrases in the Google n-grams viewer (“cracked/broke an egg”, “crack/break the eggs”, etc.) gives the impression that in the late 19th century *break* became more common, but that recently *crack* has been making a bit of a comeback.

[image: Google n-grams viewer "crack an egg" vs. "break an egg"]

The relative frequencies vary quite a bit between phrasings (eg in “breaking/cracking eggs”, *breaking* dominates by a large margin, presumably due to “You can’t make an omelette without…” and similar phrases).  However, the same historical trends seem to hold for all the phrasings I tried.

As @nohat points out, *crack* can be used with this meaning in other contexts as well, though it seems to be less common in general than it is with eggs.

Answer (score 5):

You're right about the meanings of the words. But both verbs are used with egg. See the examples:

> Never **crack eggs** directly into the bowl that you are building your recipe in.
>
> **Cracking an egg** open and separating the egg yolks is quite easy.
>
> Make sure they're not wearing any rings and challenge them to **break an egg** this way.
>
> **Breaking an egg** with one hand takes finesse, but using two hands to **crack eggs** works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

The verb *crack* can mean “to break by creating cracks”, or as Merriam-Webster Dictionary [says](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crack) “1a: to break so that fissures appear on the surface <crack a mirror>”

Comment: Yep. And we all know "you can't make an omelet without *breaking* a few eggs."

Answer (score -1):

The Online dictionary suggests you can crack something, meaning snap or break apart, or crack meaning break without separation of parts. I suspect cracking an egg is what it suggests is the informal usage *open for consumption*, as in to *crack a few beers* (beer being something it is impossible to crack in the strict sense of the word).

[Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/crack) suggests also *break or cause to break with a sharp sound*.

Comment: The usage with beer is recent and figurative; the usage with eggs is old and literal!  They really don’t seem the same to me at all.